# Superscript Unicode for %sign

Tags: unicode, spss, superscript

Does anyone know % sign superscript Unicode? I want to write 50% as a superscript in SPSS chart. I found all other unicode but couldn't find % sign. Is there any?

Comment: Wouldn’t the symbol be its own entity and the superscript formatting be taken care of separately?

Comment: You should use other way to add superscript. Note SPSS is older then Unicode, so they will have for sure some way to do it (involving the font, not using Unicode, which it is considered bad practice for formatting)

Answer (score 3):

No. These are the [only percent signs](https://www.fileformat.info/search/google.htm?q=PERCENT+SIGN&domains=www.fileformat.info&sitesearch=www.fileformat.info&client=pub-6975096118196151&forid=1&channel=1657057343&ie=UTF-8&oe=UTF-8&cof=GALT%3A%23008000%3BGL%3A1%3BDIV%3A%23336699%3BVLC%3A663399%3BAH%3Acenter%3BBGC%3AFFFFFF%3BLBGC%3A336699%3BALC%3A0000FF%3BLC%3A0000FF%3BT%3A000000%3BGFNT%3A0000FF%3BGIMP%3A0000FF%3BFORID%3A11&hl=en) in Unicode:

- % 'PERCENT SIGN' (U+0025)
- ％ 'FULLWIDTH PERCENT SIGN' (U+FF05)
- ﹪ 'SMALL PERCENT SIGN' (U+FE6A)
- 'TAG PERCENT SIGN' (U+E0025) (This is for "tags," generally used for regional flags; it's not printable)
- ٪ 'ARABIC PERCENT SIGN' (U+066A)

Additionally there are two "percent-like" characters:

- ‰ 'PER MILLE SIGN' (U+2030)
- ‱ 'PER TEN THOUSAND SIGN' (U+2031)

There are no superscripts. As a rule, this should done with a font, not a Unicode character.